# How to prevent jquery click function?

Tags: jquery

On this page http://jsfiddle.net/wQhaH/1/ I try this:

User can click up to 3 time any where of document include link, buttons etc. After 3 click, I want to prevent user to click ANY OBJECT ON THE SCREEN. You can think all page elements are blocked.

I tryed `e.preventDefault()` function but it doesn't work. Can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wQhaH/2/

```
var count = 0;
$(document).click(function(e) {
    count++;
    if(count > 2) {
        $("body").append('<div class="block-ui">');
        $(document).unbind("click");
    }
    $('#log').html( $('#log').html() + "Clicked Document !<br>" );
});

$("#mylink").click(function(event) {
    $('#log').html( $('#log').html() + "Clicked !<br>" );
});
```

Comment: Very Nice. I see what your doing. Your just breaking the webpage. By adding an free HTML element. Haha, very smart thinking. Would of never of thought of that ;)

Comment: @Shawn31313, I actually use similar with ajax requests when it doesn't make sense to let the user interact while the ajax request is still going :P

Answer (score 1):

Use the `unbind()` function in jquery

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
if(count > 2){
  $('*').unbind('click');
  $(document).unbind('click');
}
```

This will unbind click events from all elements of the DOM. The '*' selector selects all elements but not the `document`, so you have to also unbind from the document if you have any click handlers binded to the document.

Comment: I don't want to unbind or any other solution. I want to use preventDefault.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you expect to achieve. Using `preventDefault` inside of the document click handler won't stop anything inside the document from firing, as those events fire first then bubble up to the document, which fires last. Using unbind will _definitely_ work and is the best solution. The only other way is to switch a global variable to **false** when the document click reaches 3, and then wrap each other click event in an **if** statement that asks if the global var is true.